# Why does my loop only continue when using SOUT?

Tags: java, netbeans

So I have a pretty big project but finally boiled down the problem to the following situation.

I have the main class "LoopTest" and another class "RandomClassObject"

**LoopTest:**

```
public class LoopTest {

static RandomClassObject rco;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    rco = new RandomClassObject();
    System.out.println("RCO has finished");
}
```

}

**RandomClassObject:**

```
public class RandomClassObject {

JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JButton button = new JButton("Click Me");
boolean created = false;

public RandomClassObject() {
    button.addActionListener(this::buttonActionPerformed);
    frame.add(button);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    while (!created) {
        //System.out.println("Done"); //This needs to be uncommented to work.
    }
    System.out.println("It was been Created");
}

public void buttonActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    created = true;
}
```

So I want my RandomClassObject to wait until the button is pressed.
I have a boolean "created" and have a while loop that loops until said boolean is changed to true.

When running with the SOUT "Done" commented out, I click the button but never get the second SOUT "It had been Created".

When running with the SOUT "Done" uncommented, I get spammed with "Done"'s and once I click the button I receive the SOUT "It has been created."

I need help understanding why I have to put a SOUT in my While loop for my loop to ever exit on buttonClick.

Sorry if this is a obvious error and thanks for any replies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a synchronization issue. The button click is happening in the event thread, and your loop (running in the main thread) is never seeing the update it makes. Because you don't force memory synchronization between the two threads the machine is free to ignore changes.

The call to `System.out.println` has the side effect of forcing memory synchronization, allowing your main thread to see the changes made by the event thread.

To fix this, make `created` an `AtomicBoolean` or add the `synchronized` keyword to your `complete` method.

In any case the loop is a bad way to achieve this result. Consider driving your completion logic from an event listener on the button.

You say you need to pause your main thread until the character is created. One way to do this is to use a latch:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test...");
        JButton button = new JButton("Click Me");
        button.addActionListener(e -> latch.countDown());
        frame.add(button);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        // Wait here for the click in the event thread
        latch.await();

        System.out.println("Clicked!");

        frame.dispose();
    }
}
```

Calling `latch.await()` will block your main thread until your event thread releases the latch with `latch.countDown()`.

Comment: Thanks @teppic ! The synchronized keyword ahead of my complete method helped. I get that you say using an Event Listener for the button would be better, but I NEED this loop to pause the main program from continuing until the object RCO has been clicked.

Comment: There are a few ways of doing it. I've edited the answer and added one suggestion.